# What is the code point of a mathematical h when one uses unicode-math?

Tags: unicode-math, math-fonts

It seems that the rest of the minuscules are at U+1d44e ..., but the h, which is called Planck's constant, is not used for h.  I got this impression from replacing all these glyphs and observing the expected result except in the case of *h*.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Apparently the Unicode Block *Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols* does not have the small italic `h`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols or https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf. It belongs to the *Letterlike Symbols* with codepoint U+210E. However I'm not sure how on-topic for this site this question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s ℎ (U+210E), in a different block than you checked.  [Here’s a useful reference.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject)

Note that ISO style says to typeset constants upright, which would be `\symup{h}` or `\mathrm{h}`.  There is also an upright ħ (U+0127) distinct from ℏ (U+210F).  However, this does not appear to be common practice in mathematical physics.